# Sort/clean a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, ubuntu

I have an MySQL database that looks like this, where it is no system of the valuses in the columns. What are the easiest way to copy this over to an new database and sort it`?

```
+----+---------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
| ID |      ID1      |    Value1    |      ID2      |    Value2    |      ID3      |    Value3    |      ID4      |    Value4    |
+----+---------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
|  1 | Picture       | picture1.png | Documentation | doc1.pdf     | Height        | 10           | Volume        | 150          |
|  2 | Documentation | doc2.pdf     | Picture       | picture2.png | Volume        | 150          | Height        | 10           |
|  3 | Volume        | 200          | Height        | 20           | Picture       | picture3.png | Documentation | doc3.pdf     |
|  4 | Height        | 25           | Volume        | 250          | Documentation | Doc4.pdf     | Picture       | picture4.png |
+----+---------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
```

I want it to looks something like this ID1=Picture, ID2=Documentation and so..?

```
+----+---------+--------------+---------------+----------------+--------+--------------+--------+--------+
| ID |   ID1   |      Value1  |        ID2    |         Value2 |  ID3   |     Value3   |  ID4   | Value4 |
+----+---------+--------------+---------------+----------------+--------+--------------+--------+--------+
|  1 | Picture | picture1.png | Documentation | doc1.pdf       | Volume |          100 | Height |     10 |
|  2 | Picture | picture2.png | Documentation | doc2.pdf       | Volume |          150 | Height |     15 |
|  3 | Picture | picture3.png | Documentation | doc3.pdf       | Volume |          200 | Height |     20 |
|  4 | Picture | picture4.png | Documentation | doc4.pdf       | Volume |          250 | Height |     25 |
+----+---------+--------------+---------------+----------------+--------+--------------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: When you say database you mean table, right?

Comment: It seems that you got only one table within all the info, when you should probably have several in order to get a better database model

Comment: It looks like you want a pivot table query. Are you trying to take (in your example) the data from 4 rows and put it in one row in the destination table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the data you have provided, this will work:

```
CREATE TABLE Table2
    (`ID` int, 
     `ID1` varchar(13), `Value1` varchar(12), 
     `ID2` varchar(13), `Value2` varchar(12), 
     `ID3` varchar(13), `Value3` varchar(12), 
     `ID4` varchar(13), `Value4` varchar(12));
INSERT INTO Table2
    (SELECT id, 'Picture' as ID1,
     CASE WHEN id1='Picture' THEN value1 WHEN id2='Picture' THEN value2 WHEN id3='Picture' THEN value3 ELSE value4 END AS value1,
    'Documentation' AS ID2,
    CASE WHEN id1='Documentation' THEN value1 WHEN id2='Documentation' THEN value2 WHEN id3='Documentation' THEN value3 ELSE value4 END AS value2,
    'Volume' AS ID3,
    CASE WHEN id1='Volume' THEN value1 WHEN id2='Volume' THEN value2 WHEN id3='Volume' THEN value3 ELSE value4 END AS value3,
    'Height' AS ID4,
    CASE WHEN id1='Height' THEN value1 when id2='Height' THEN value2 when id3='Height' THEN value3 ELSE value4 END AS value4
    FROM Table1);

SELECT * FROM Table2
```

Output:

```
ID    ID1      Value1        ID2            Value2    ID3    Value3    ID4    Value4
1     Picture  picture1.png  Documentation  doc1.pdf  Volume 150       Height 10 
2     Picture  picture2.png  Documentation  doc2.pdf  Volume 150       Height 10 
3     Picture  picture3.png  Documentation  doc3.pdf  Volume 200       Height 20 
4     Picture  picture4.png  Documentation  Doc4.pdf  Volume 250       Height 25
```

At this point you should probably consider changing the structure of your table, as this table has a lot of redundant information in it (ID1 is always 'Picture', ID2 is always 'Documentation' etc.) so you can probably remove those fields and just have fields named Picture, Documentation etc. You could do that using this query:

```
CREATE TABLE Table3
    (`ID` int, 
     `Picture` varchar(12), 
     `Documentation` varchar(12), 
     `Volume` varchar(12), 
     `Height` varchar(12));
INSERT INTO Table3
    (SELECT id,
     CASE WHEN id1='Picture' THEN value1 WHEN id2='Picture' THEN value2 WHEN id3='Picture' THEN value3 ELSE value4 END AS Picture,
    CASE WHEN id1='Documentation' THEN value1 WHEN id2='Documentation' THEN value2 WHEN id3='Documentation' THEN value3 ELSE value4 END AS Documentation,
    CASE WHEN id1='Volume' THEN value1 WHEN id2='Volume' THEN value2 WHEN id3='Volume' THEN value3 ELSE value4 END AS Volume,
    CASE WHEN id1='Height' THEN value1 when id2='Height' THEN value2 when id3='Height' THEN value3 ELSE value4 END AS Height
    FROM Table1);

SELECT * FROM Table3
```

Output:

```
ID   Picture       Documentation  Volume  Height
1    picture1.png  doc1.pdf       150     10 
2    picture2.png  doc2.pdf       150     10 
3    picture3.png  doc3.pdf       200     20 
4    picture4.png  Doc4.pdf       250     25
```

Answer (score 0):

for a better DB Model Use proper Column Names

record_id,image_name,image_url,doc_name,doc_url,volume,height
and make record_id Auto Increment